# Rails get field from another table in admin part

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

In my app, i have admin subfolder, and controller there, and method:

```
class Admin::UserGroupsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @pre_usergroups = UserGroup.all
    @user_groups = Kaminari.paginate_array(@pre_usergroups).page(params[:page]).per(50)
    render :layout => 'admin'
  end
end
```

route:

```
namespace :admin do
resources :user_groups
end
```

and model (not in subdirectory admin):

```
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :group_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:user_not_chosen)}
  validates :group_id, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:group_not_chosen)}


  def get_group_name(id)
    @gr = Group.find(id)
    @gr.name
  end

  def get_user_name(id)
    @user = User.find(id)
    @user.email
  end
end
```

Also i didn't see validation message's and it's working.... it skip validation:

and view:

```
%table.table.table-striped
  %tr
    %th
      Название группы:
    %th
      Пользователь:  
  -@user_groups.each do |u|
    %tr  
      %td
        = u.get_group_name(group_id)
      %td
        = u.user_id
```

But why i get

```
 undefined local variable or method `group_id' for #<#<Class:0xb352734>:0xab437dc>
```

So i didn't go to method in model...
How can i access model method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as stated in the error `group_id` is not defined which is true.
You should be calling it as follows:

`= u.get_group_name(u.group_id)`

because `group_id` is an attribute of the `UserGroup` object

However, I don't see why you are making the methods `get_group_name` and `get_user_name`, why don't you just use `u.group.name` and `u.user.email`?

Comment: ahahaha, lol.... realy, how can i forget it.... it is not good idea to not sleep for 2 nights)  thanks, and sorry for such question

Comment: you are welcome, please consider using the associations directly as I added in the answer.

Comment: becouse now i have some troubles with relations... i don't know them now, so i decided to hardcode methods for a while

Comment: also, maybe you can give short advice, why in admin part i didn't see work of validators, shortly, to do not open new question?